# array of pointers *(*(string+i)+j). (Is This Possible?)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here in this code i am trying to reverse a string using a function.Here i used an array of pointers to store some arrays.`*(*(string+i)+j)`this line works for `i=0` but as soon as `i` is incremented to `i=1` it give a segmentation fault. I am unable to understand what could be the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char**reverse(char**);
int main()
{
    char *final[2],*s[] = {
      "To err is human...",
      "But to really mess things up...",
      "One needs to know C!!"
      } ;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        puts(s[i]);
    reverse(s);
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        puts(final[i]);
    return 0;
}
char** reverse(char*string[2])
{   
    char *temp[2];
    int len,i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        len=strlen(string[i]);
        k=0;
        for(j=len-1;j>=0;j--)
        {   
            *(*(temp+i)+k)=*(*(string+i)+j);
            /*this line work for i=0 but give segmentation fault for i=1;*/

            printf("%c",*(*(temp+i)+k));
            k++;
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Someone stole your tab-key. May wanna chase that guy down.

Comment: `temp` is only two slots wide, index-dereferencable by `[0..1]`. You're looping to `2` : `for(i=0;i<=2;i++)`, and thus invoking undefined behavior on access to `*(temp+i)`. Worse, the next "spot" in your automatic variable space below `temp` is `len` which is likely being overwritten with an ascii-char, and thereby changing the condition in your `for-j` loop.

Comment: are you allergic to blanks and whitespaces?

Comment: @WhozCraig `temp[0]` & `temp[1]` is uninitialised and OP is *trying* to store data pointed by each. So there are problems even before `i` reaches 2 :)

Comment: @PeterMiehle Iamnotsurewhatyoumean,looksfinetome :)

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few problems here:

1. The pointers in temp are uninitialized, and temp is a local stack array. You can't return it, because it will be out of scope
2. You are not doing anything with the returned value of 'reverse'
3. Your initial array is size 3, not size 2.
4. There's no need to use the confusing (*(string+i)+j) notation. string[i][j] will work just as well, and is much more readable.
5. You don't terminate your strings after reversing them. You need temp[i][k]='\0'; after the for loop to do this.

The simplest reworking of your code to give the results you want is probably something like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

char**reverse(char**);

int main()
{
    char **final,*s[] = {
    "To err is human...",
    "But to really mess things up...",
    "One needs to know C!!"
    } ;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    puts(s[i]);
    final = reverse(s);
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    puts(final[i]);
    return 0;
}

char**reverse(char*string[3])
{
    char **temp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2);
    int len,i,j,k;

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);
    }

    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)   
    {
        len=strlen(string[i]);
        k=0;
        for(j=len-1;j>=0;j--)
        {   
            *(*(temp+i)+k)=*(*(string+i)+j);
            printf("%c",*(*(temp+i)+k));
            k++;
        }
        temp[i][k]='\0';
        printf("\n");
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Program output is:

> To err is human...
>
> But to really mess things up...
>
> One needs to know C!!
>
> ...namuh si rre oT
>
> ...pu sgniht ssem yllaer ot tuB
>
> !!C wonk ot sdeen enO

Comment: never cast the result of malloc()

Comment: Sorry - I was using a C++ compiler to test the code. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the pain to explain all these +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `char *temp[2];` is declared but is never allocated any memory (with malloc or such). Therefore it is pointing to undefined locations of memory. I think this is causing your segmentation fault.

That it works for i = 0 is probably luck :o I.e. temp[0] contains a char* which may point to valid memory, but temp[1] may not (seg fault). You need to allocate the memory before you use it.

```
temp[i] = malloc(strlen(string[i]));
```

Or somthing like this....

Answer (score 0):

final is of type "char *final[2]" but your loop is

```
for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    puts(final[i]);
```

that gives 3 to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code like below, I ran the code and it works! i hope this is helpful for you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void reverse(char**);

int main()
{
    char *s[] = {
      "To err is human...",
      "But to really mess things up...",
      "One needs to know C!!"
      } ;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        puts(s[i]);
    //reverse the string!
    reverse(s);
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        puts(s[i]);

    return 0;
}

//function to reverse the string
void reverse(char*string[2])
{   
    char *temp;
    int len,i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        len=strlen(string[i]);
        k=0;
        temp = (char *)malloc((len * sizeof(char)) + 1);
        for(j=len-1;j>=0;j--)
        {   
            temp[k] = string[i][j];
            printf("%c",temp[k]);
            k++;
        }
        temp[k] = '\0';
        //puts(temp[i]);
        string[i] = temp;  // after reversing the string store it back to string!
        printf("\n");

    }
}
```